# Laptop spacebar key too low down

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure

Today I was typing and after I pressed Space-bar a few times, it continued inputting on it's own. I took the space-bar off, and nothing seems to be stuck or broken; there is no debris and the clips are in mint condition.

I realized that the small (I don't know it's name) thingy that pushes down to input a space was slightly out of place. I fixed this, yet now when I placed the space-bar back on, it hangs too low down therefore inputting multiple spaces.

Is there anything I can do to solve this? I was given this laptop as a gift two days ago.

If anyone needs to know what kind of laptop it is, it's a Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Pro w3515.

Answer (score 1):

If this was used when it was given to you, the keyboard may be worn and needing replacement.

Typical laptop keyboard components include a rubber cup under the key retainer which holds the key up. This has probably become compressed over time and needs to be replaced.

[image]

You can purchase a replacement keyboard or search for the replacement parts yourself. If you can not find parts, or deem it not worth the expense, simply move the cup from rarely used keys like <kbd>~</kbd> or <kbd>Pause</kbd>.

Lastly, you can connect an external keyboard.